# Submersions and complex structure

Tags: differential-topology, covering-spaces, complex-manifolds

Let $f : \Lambda \rightarrow X$ be a continuous surjective map, where $\Lambda$ is a complex manifold and $X$ a topological space. Suppose that for all $x \in X$, there is a neighborhood $U_x$ of $X$ and a continuous map : $g : U_x \rightarrow \Lambda$ which is a right inverse of $f$.

Does this always allow one to define a complex atlas on $X$ ? More precisely, is it necessarily true in this generality that the transition maps $g_1 \circ g_2^{-1}=g_1 \circ f$ are holomorphic, when $g_i$ are local sections of $f$ defined on a common open set in $X$ ?

Comment: Never mind, this question : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51422/pushing-complex-structure-forward shows that this is not true even for covering maps. What works best apparently is *pulling back* complex structures instead of pushing it forward like here.